# L and M are midpoints of equilateral triangle ABC, and LM meets the circumcircle of the triangle at Y. Prove LM/MY is the golden ratio.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, golden-ratio

So far I've tried to split the triangle into smaller 30-60-90 triangles, and letting LM = x make some proportions and see if they can be related in anyway. I'm not sure what to do about MY though.

Any Ideas? Any and all help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Its a duplicate but I can't find original at the moment. Idea is to extend $YL$ to $X$ on circle and observe $LX=MY=y$.  Then $AM\cdot MC = MY\cdot MX$ leads to $x^2=y(x+y)$ which is as good as $(x/y)^2=(x/y)+1$.

Comment: How do you know that AM x MC = MY x MX? I got a bit confused at how to relate them at that part. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: It follows either from similarity of triangles AMX and YMC, or from "Intersecting Chords" theorem (look it up on wikipedia).

Comment: Great, make sense now. Thank you!

Comment: ARML 1997 team round problem 2 if my memory is good